# Loading Bitmap in ImageView before Activity started

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am letting my users pick a background from their Gallery and I save this to internal memory:

When user picked the background:

```
new ImageBackground(getApplicationContext()).save(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData()));
```

Saving the image:

```
private void saveImageToFile(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(createFile());
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private File createFile() {
    File directory = context.getDir(DIRECTORY_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new File(directory, FILENAME);
}
```

So at this point my image is saved to internal memory. Now when the user starts the application this image should be loaded in an ImageView. I used ASync, Picasso and Glide to do this, this works fine BUT; when I use those methods, on starting up the application the background at the beginning is always black (default background) for like half a second.

What I am doing now is using the code below. This works fine for now, but I always read that it is better to load with ASync or Glide/Picasso.

```
private Bitmap getImageBackground(){
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(createFile());
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Default background
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.background);
}
```

So what I want; the background should be loaded in the ImageView when the Activity is shown to the user (so I do not see a black background for like half a second).

How can I achieve this? Or is it ok how I do it now?

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso/Glide with cache enabled so that it will load your images as soon as possible :) AsyncTask is less recommended.

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(imageView);
```

Picasso will do automatic caching for you :)

Comment: What does the cache do? Does it load the image before the activity is shown to the user?

Comment: if the image is displayed in the prev activity, the library will keep it in the cache so that it will get loaded in the next activity almost immediately. Don't overthink about it,  leave it to the library. They will take care of it.

Comment: Just use picasso to load your image, picasso will do the rest for you :)  Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)    
    .into(imageView);

Comment: Well, I already tried it, but I am not satisfied with the result, because I still see a black background at the beginning. I really want it to be loaded already before the user see the Activity.

Comment: since your imageView lies inside of your Activity, you can't load your image before the activity itself ready.

Comment: So I guess only option is to use it as I do now? It seems to work fine though.

Answer (score 0):

> I always read that it is better to load with ASync or Glide/Picasso.

It is advised to do so because image loading is an expensive task. If done on the main thread, it will block the app. In other words, the app will be unresponsive to the user as the thread will be busy loading the image. So this is the "correct way" to load image. Also it is better to use a proper library for image loading than just an AsyncTask.

The imageView is black at the start because the image is not loaded yet. To counter this you can use a placeholder image that will be displayed in the imageView until the actual image is loaded.

Picasso supports both download and error placeholders as optional features.

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

See [this](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for you reaction. But with this solution I get another image shown first and like after half a second the correct image. I would like to see that the correct image is shown before the user sees the activity.

Comment: @tomhogenkamp sometimes the image is too large that it needs time to load.. Thats why we use placeholders (which are generally smaller in size) to take its place until the image is finished loading.. Or you can use an indeterminate progress bar till your image is loaded, but you can't just load image into activity before it starts.